# onmouseover, onmouseout,onclick function Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, css

i have a menu for my page,here is the Onmouseover, Onmouseout img

```
<img id='wits' class="wits1" src="Images/MenuInWhite/ContactButton1.png" onmouseover="this.src='Images/mouseover/ContactButton2.png'"
        onmouseout="this.src='Images/MenuInWhite/ContactButton1.png'"  /><br />
    <img id='city' class="city1" src="Images/MenuInWhite/ActivitiesButton1.png" onmouseover="this.src='Images/mouseover/ActivitiesButton2.png'"
        onmouseout="this.src='Images/MenuInWhite/ActivitiesButton1.png'" /><br />
    <img id='organise' class="city1" onmouseout="this.src='Images/MenuInWhite/CruisesButton1.png';"
        onmouseover="this.src='Images/mouseover/CruisesButton2.png';" src="Images/MenuInWhite/CruisesButton1.png" /><br />
    <img id='people' class="city1" onmouseout="this.src='Images/MenuInWhite/HomeButton1.png';"
        onmouseover="this.src='Images/mouseover/HomeButton2.png';" src="Images/MenuInWhite/HomeButton1.png" /><br />
```

whenever i put my mouse over images the images must change and when i take my mouse away it must be changed to the original picture, it's working fine,,

i'd like to know how to do whenever i select any image, that image must be changed to the image which was displayed while moving the mouse across the image. and when i select any other image the same process must take place but the previous image that was changed must be changed back to the original picture.

pls help me out for this solution,,

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here's one pure JavaScript solution for that, May be this could help

```
function isMSIE() 
{
   var ie7 = 
   (document.all && !window.opera && window.XMLHttpRequest) ? true : false;
   return ie7;
}
function getParent(element, depth) 
{
   var rVal = element;
   if (isMSIE()) {
       for (i = 0; i < depth; i++)
       rVal = rVal.parentElement;
   }
   else {
        for (i = 0; i < depth; i++)
        rVal = rVal.parentNode;
    }
    return rVal;
}
function clicked(sender)
{
    var parent   = getParent(sender, 1);
    var imgs = parent.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
    for(i=0; i<imgs.length; i++)
    {
       if (imgs[i] != sender) {
          imgs[i].src = 'Images/MenuInWhite/ContactButton1.png';
          imgs[i].onmouseout = 
            function () { this.src = 'Images/MenuInWhite/HomeButton1.png'; };
       }
       else {
          imgs[i].src = 'Images/MenuInWhite/HomeButton1.png';
          imgs[i].onmouseout = null;
       }
        if(imgs[i]!=sender)
          imgs[i].src = 'Images/MenuInWhite/HomeButton1.png';
    }
}
```

---

```
<div>
   <img id='wits' class="wits1" 
      src="Images/MenuInWhite/ContactButton1.png"    
      onmouseover="this.src='Images/mouseover/ContactButton2.png'"
      onmouseout="this.src='Images/MenuInWhite/ContactButton1.png'"
      onclick="clicked(this);"  /><br />
   // Just add this onclick="clicked(this);" on each img
</div>
```

Comment: Yogi-->it's not working, element id is not working here    
        if(imgs[i]!=sender)  alert('123')
            imgs[i].src = 'Images/MenuInWhite/HomeButton1.png';

Comment: yogi--> yea i have added onclick and the above javascript in my page and tried,, it's not changing,,,,,

Comment: @ShaiRiyaz have a look at it now it's working actually I didn't removed that onmouseout handler and after click when mouse outs from that img it changes back to normal, silly mistake :)